# Doing animation in core animation after adding layer to superlayer

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I have the following code:

```
// create sublayer
sublayer.position = p1;
[superlayer addSublayer:sublayer];
sublayer.position = p2;
```

`sublayer` just appeares at `p2` instead of animating from `p1` to `p2`. is there a way I can make it animate from `p1` to `p2`?

Comment: You have not added any animation code, hence no animation is taking place.

Comment: @Till: when I do something like `sublayer.position = something;` on user input, the layer is animated without any animation code

Answer (score 0):

Your `sublayer` should be displayed first. If your `sublayer` is just created and added, you can write something like this:

```
{
    ...
    sublayer.position = p1;
    [superlayer addSublayer:sublayer];
    [self performSelector:@selector(changePosition:)
                    delay:0
               withObject:sublayer];
    ...
}

-(void)changePosition:(CALayer*)layer
{
    layer.position = p2;
}
```